# Hide/Show an element automatically( not using a keyup() or click ) when an input field is entered/selected a value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an `<input>` tag in my form that takes a value from **Bootstrap Datepicker**.

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label>Select Date</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input name="date_info" type="text" class="form-control datepick validate_date" placeholder="Date" readonly>
      </div>
      <small class="validate_date_error">This field is mandatory!</small>          
      <small class="validate_date_success">This is Fine!</small>
  </div>

  <button class="next">Next</button>
</div>
```

I'm trying to achieve a functionality as in, On click of `.next` button, if date is not selected or is empty, I'm displaying `.validate_date_error`.

If date is selected, without a click or [Enter] key, I want to show `.validate_date_success`.

Following is my JS

```
$(function() {
    $('.datepick').datepicker({
        autoclose: true,
        format: 'dd-mm-yyyy'
    });
});


$(".next").click( function() {
    var check_date = $(".validate_date").val();

    if( check_date === "" ){
       $(this).parent().find('.validate_date_error').show();
    }else {
       $(this).parent().find('.validate_date_error').hide();
       $(this).parent().find('.validate_date_success').show();
    }
});
```

If anyone could solve this for me, it'll be of gret help.

I have updated my code here [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zNbUT/731/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On selecting a value from datepicker, you can use the onchange event,

```
$('input[name=date]').change(function() { 
        var check_date = $(".validate_date").val();
        $('.validate_date_error').hide();
        if(check_date === ""){
            $('.validate_date_success').hide();
    }else{
            $('.validate_date_success').show();
    }
});
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Thank you for the solution @Shubham Shukla !:)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the function change given by JQuery. This function is called everytime the value in an input changed, so it is perfect for you.

You could do something like this, first of all set an id in your input something like that :

```
<input id="date" name="date_info" type="text" class="form-control datepick validate_date" placeholder="Date" readonly>
```

then in you js file add the change method :

```
$('#date').change(function () {
    if($(this).val() !== '') //If a date had been picked
    {
        //show success message
    }
    else
    {
        //show error message
    } 
})
```

Of course this is the basic, you can improve the condition to fit as much as you want.

Here is your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zNbUT/750/

Hope it helps you

Comment: Thank you for the response @Lucas Tambarin ! The else{} part in the callback() always shows up .validate_date_success if the input field is empty. If I choose not to have it, this solutions holds good for me. And I preferred to have name attribute rather than an id.

Comment: I am glad it helped you, but i don't see what you're saying because for me the date_error always appear when it's empty and when the date is set the date_success appears

Comment: Yes, you got it! On page load( this is what I referred to always) I did not want to show date_error. Wanted to show date_error on click of .next button. But when date value is selected wanted to show date_success automatically without click or keyup. So, I could achieve this by removing the else{} part in the code. May be I didn't explain it in the question to the point. Just a small change though! :) @Lucas Tambarin

Answer (score 0):

How about this, using the `.on(event, callback)` method

```
$(function() {
    $('.datepick').datepicker({
        autoclose: true,
        format: 'dd-mm-yyyy'
    });
});

$("input[name='date']").on('change', function (e) {
    if (e.target.value) {
    $('.validate_date_error').hide();
    $('.validate_date_success').show();
  } else {
    $('.validate_date_error').show();
  }
})

$(".next").click( function() {
            var check_date = $(".validate_date").val();

      if( check_date === "" ){
        $(this).parent().find('.validate_date_error').show();
      }else {
        $(this).parent().find('.validate_date_error').hide();
        $(this).parent().find('.validate_date_success').show();
      }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the response @gillyhl ! The else{} part in the callback() always shows up the .validate_date_error if the input field is empty. If I remove that, this solution is perfect for me.

Comment: Oh yeah. My bad. Logic fail :p

Comment: But this sol was one more variant to my question! Thanks for that @gillyhl :)